# average from a dictionary (values)

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm trying to change the result so if there are 2 grades in values it will replace the 2 grades with the average. I tried so many techniques to do that but failed.
I need to write a solution for the average and to delete the 2 values of the grades.

I wrote this code:

```
def myDict(grades, teachers):
    Dict={}
    for i1 in grades:
        for i2 in teachers:
            key=i2[1]
            value=[]

            Dict[key]=value #{'Statistics': [], 'Philosophy': [], 'Computer': [], 'Physics': [], 'English': []}
            for i1 in grades:
                if key==i1[-1]:
                    value.append(i1[0]) #{'Statistics': [23560, 23452], 'Philosophy': [], 'Computer': [23415, 12345], 'Physics': [23452, 23459], 'English': [12345]}

            for i1 in grades:
                if key==i1[-1]:
                    value.append(i1[1])

            value_size=len(value)
            if value_size>2:
                end=int(value_size)/2
                for i in value[-1:end]:
                    print float(count(i)/value_size)

    print Dict

grades = [[12345,75,'English'],
             [23452,83,'Physics'],
             [23560,81,'Statistics'],
             [23415,61,'Computer'],
             [23459,90,'Physics'],    
             [12345,75,'Computer'],
             [23452,100,'Statistics']]

teachers = [['Aharoni','English'],
               ['Melamed','Physics'],
               ['Kaner','Computer'],
               ['Zloti','Statistics'],
               ['Korman','Philosophy']]

print myDict(grades, teachers)
```

The result is:

```
>>> 
{'Statistics': [23560, 23452, 81, 100], 'Philosophy': [], 'Computer': [23415, 12345, 61, 75], 'Physics': [23452, 23459, 83, 90], 'English': [12345, 75]}
None
>>>
```

**What i want to get (it is in process, i am stuck in this level):**

```
{ 'Aharoni': [12345, 75.0], 'Kaner': [23415, 12345, 68.0], 'Melamed':   [23452, 23459, 86.5], 'Korman': [], 'Zloti': [23560, 23452, 90.5] }
```

Comment: Do your data structures for grades and teachers have to be list of lists like that? Can't you re-structure it to make it easier to handle the data?

Comment: No, unfortunately it has to stay like that

Comment: OK. So, what *should* be the final data structure? What you showed is the output you are getting that you say is incorrect.

Comment: yes, what i want to get (it is in process, i am stuck in this level):

{
'Aharoni': [12345, 75.0], 'Kaner': [23415, 12345, 68.0], 'Melamed': [23452, 23459, 86.5], 'Korman': [], 'Zloti': [23560, 23452, 90.5]
}

Comment: Please put that in your original question and explain that is what you are looking to output

Comment: @idjaw I hope it's ok now

Comment: Copy pasting your code and it doesn't run. Also, what is count? You need to ensure that when you are providing code that you provide the proper explanation of what it is going on in your code.

Comment: sorry i know, it shuold be "sum"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this simple loop:

```
myDict = {}

for teacher, subject in teachers:
    values = []
    scores = []
    for i1, i2, s in grades:
        if subject == s:
            values.append(i1)
            scores.append(i2)

    if scores:
        average = sum(scores) / len(scores)
        values.append(average)

    myDict[teacher] = values
```

First, iterate trough the teachers, and for each matching subject in the grade list, append `i1` and `i2` to some list.

At the end of the iteration, you can easily compute the average of `i2` values (if the list is not empty) and then update your dictionnary.

---

The output with your data would be:

```
{
    'Korman': [],
    'Melamed': [23452, 23459, 86.5],
    'Zloti': [23560, 23452, 90.5],
    'Aharoni': [12345, 75.0],
    'Kaner': [23415, 12345, 68.0]
}
```

Comment: @Netta I recently updated the code, because there was a ZeroDivision error. The result looks like what you was expecting, if this is not the case, please explain me what is wrong.

Comment: I don't why but if i insert it to a function it doesn't work

Comment: TypeError: 'function' object does not support item assignment

Comment: @Netta I guess this is because `myDict` is used as a variable and function name at the same time, this is incorrect. Look at this example, I renamed `myDict` with `my_dict` and it works: https://ideone.com/EkCli2

Comment: Thank you so much @Delgan! You made my day :-)

Answer (score 1):

List comprehensions are a great way to deal with a data structure like that:

```
def myDict(grades, teachers):
    subjects = [x[1] for x in teachers]
    d = {}
    for s in subjects:
        subject_grades_records = [x for x in grades if x[2] == s]
        value = [x[0] for x in subject_grades_records]
        if len(value) > 0:
            value.append(sum(x[1] for x in subject_grades_records) / float(len(subject_grades_records)))
        teacher = [x[0] for x in teachers if x[1] == s][0]
        d[teacher] = value
    return d


grades = [[12345,75,'English'],
             [23452,83,'Physics'],
             [23560,81,'Statistics'],
             [23415,61,'Computer'],
             [23459,90,'Physics'],    
             [12345,75,'Computer'],
             [23452,100,'Statistics']]

teachers = [['Aharoni','English'],
               ['Melamed','Physics'],
               ['Kaner','Computer'],
               ['Zloti','Statistics'],
               ['Korman','Philosophy']]

print(repr(myDict(grades, teachers)))

# {'Kaner': [23415, 12345, 68.0], 'Aharoni': [12345, 75.0], 'Zloti': [23560, 23452, 90.5], 'Melamed': [23452, 23459, 86.5], 'Korman': []}
```